# Error while running ssrs subscription using windows file share

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In log files i have this error:

> Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException:
>   AuthzInitializeContextFromSid: Win32 error: 5; possible reason -
>   service account doesn't have rights to check domain user SIDs.,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ServerConfigurationErrorException:
>   The report server has encountered a configuration error.

SSRS has account type network service and it's running. I've created folder for writing pdf report, made folder as shared and gave Everyone group full control.

When I go to website where report is, everything is working, but when I add subscription for that report, I always got same error in log. I have running  Sql profiler to catch callih procedure for report, but it's never called from subscription. 
In ssrs configuration, I haven't specified delivery email because I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your service account has the Windows Authorization Access permission.

You can find more information on this [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richin/2008/08/27/ssrs-subscription-tggau-rights-authzinitializecontextfromsid-exceptions/).

Also, whenever a new subscription is created, it is usually created under the account of the individual who is logged into the SSRS session that created it. This can be changed, and there are directions on how to do this [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/miah/2008/07/10/tip-change-the-owner-of-sql-reporting-services-subscription/).

So, in summary, you need to make sure that the account the subscription is running under is in the Windows Authorization Access (WAA) group.

Comment: I've tried to find group  (http://www.enhansoft.com/blog/configuration-manager-2012-r2-ssrs-and-windows-authorization-access-group), but I don't see it when I start typing nor in administrative tools in control panel.
Is it possible I don't have rights to access it?
I bave server 2008 installed

Comment: I actually have no idea how to fix that. In my organization, I don't have permission to alter any user or account permissions. You might contact your network or security team mentioning the problem and possible solution, and see if it rings any bells for them.

Answer (score 0):

what am I do is set Subscription and Execution same with Service account, but I'm not use Subscription actually, but this fixed issue.